# Sum of entire column in new column om SQL Server, not running sum

Tags: sql-server-2008, sum

Here is the data I have:

[image]

I want a 3rd column that has the total of the OpId column so I can do a percent of total in a 4th column. Thus, I want column 3 to read 80,801 all the way down. 80,801 is the sum of the entire OpId column

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are talking about an `over` clause.

```
Sum(OpId) over (order by (select null))
```

If you want to group / partition this into segments, like the sum of `OpId` per each `incidencetype` then add a `partition by` clause.

```
Sum(OpId) over (partition by incidencetype order by (select null))
```